# Pygame button bug with level select

Tags: pygame

I am getting an issue on my level select screen where after i press the 'play' button but when I do it goes straight to level one in stead of the level select menu which I am calling to then after that press level 1 which initiates level 1 after importing it. Code is below the relevant parts. I would like it to go from main menu to level select then to level 1 after the button is selected after being imported.

```
def main_menu():
global click
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])



    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    button_1 = pygame.Rect(399, 250, 200, 40)
    button_2 = pygame.Rect(399, 400, 200, 40)
    button_3 = pygame.Rect(399, 550, 200, 40)
    if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click :
            levelselect()
    if button_2.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            user_guide()
    if button_3.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            credits()


    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), button_1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), button_2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), button_3)


    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("button1.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (600, 80))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_1)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (200, 60))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("play.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (150, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_1)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (425, 255))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("User Guide.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (180, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_2)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (410, 405))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("credits.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (150, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_3)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (425, 555))

    click = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                click = True

    button_4 = pygame.Rect(40, 700, 80, 20)
    if button_4.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)






def levelselect():
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    global click

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    button_4 = pygame.Rect(399, 250, 200, 40)
    button_5 = pygame.Rect(399, 400, 200, 40)
    button_6 = pygame.Rect(399, 550, 200, 40)
    if button_4.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            import level1

    if button_5.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            user_guide()
    if button_6.collidepoint((mx, my)):
        if click:
            credits()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_4)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_5)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_6)

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("levelselectimg.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (600, 80))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_4)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (200, 60))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("level1.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (150, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_4)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (425, 255))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("level2.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (180, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_5)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (410, 405))

    buttonImage = pygame.image.load("level3.png")
    buttonImage = pygame.transform.scale(buttonImage, (150, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), button_6)
    screen.blit(buttonImage, (425, 555))

    click = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                click = True

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)

main_menu()
```

Comment: please format your code to make it more legible.  It's difficult to determine where your indentations are, specifically for ```def levelselect()``` and the code after.

Comment: is that what you meant?

Comment: yes..though you're going to get some errors with that kind of indentation, particularly the code for ```main()``` and ```levelselect```.  Please re-edit your code such that it is exactly as you've written.

Comment: thats the exact way i have it in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, you're going to levelselect() then immediately going to level1.

This is because both buttons are in the same position and you don't reset the click flag before the new screen is shown. The button on the second screen is immediately triggered.

Change this code:

```
if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
    if click :
        levelselect()
```

To this:

```
if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
    if click :
        click = False
        levelselect()
```

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.